# How many configurations are possible for this unique circle-arrow arrangement?

Tags: permutations, combinations, circles

8 unique points - A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H are arranged symmetrically on a circle. You are given 8 arrows. You have to connect these 8 points with these arrows in such a way that:

1. You can connect a point only to its adjacent points (A->B connection is possible, but A->C connection is not possible, unless A and C are adjacent points).
2. There should be **at least AND at most 1 arrow** directed outwards from all points (Directed outwards means that tail of the arrow has to be on the point and tip of the arrow on its adjacent point).

How many such configuration are possible? (You have to use all 8 arrows in a configuration)

Here is one such configuration:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRWHD.jpg)

Comment: Each point $A-H$ has one arrow starting from it, and that arrow can go in two different directions, so the obvious answer is $2^8=256$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Even I thought the same, but since the question seemed a bit twisted, I thought maybe I was overcounting or something. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- Count the number of ways to position the eight points on the circle.
- For each point, there are two choices for the arrow directing outward from that point.
- Account for over-counting. If you rotate a configuration, does it count as a different configuration? If you flip a configuration so that the arrangement of the points is in reverse order, but the arrows still start and end at the same points, does it count as a different configuration? [This will depend on the question-asker, it is not particularly clear to me from the question statement as-is.]